# Simple way to change the position of UIView?

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, frame, cgrect

I change the position of a UIView with following codes without changing size of the view.

```
CGRect f = aView.frame;
f.origin.x = 100; // new x
f.origin.y = 200; // new y
aView.frame = f;
```

Is there more simple way to change only the view position?

Comment: Note: It doesn't work if you are using AutoLayouts.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

```
aView.center = CGPointMake(150, 150); // set center
```

or

```
aView.frame = CGRectMake( 100, 200, aView.frame.size.width, aView.frame.size.height ); // set new position exactly
```

or

```
aView.frame = CGRectOffset( aView.frame, 10, 10 ); // offset by an amount
```

**Edit:**

I didn't compile this yet, but it should work:

```
#define CGRectSetPos( r, x, y ) CGRectMake( x, y, r.size.width, r.size.height )

aView.frame = CGRectSetPos( aView.frame, 100, 200 );
```

Comment: Yay, upvote from me as well for CGRectOffset. It cuts down on the gibberish. Gibberish I now get to spend on something else.

Comment: For Swift 3:
aView.frame = aView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 100, dy: 100)

Comment: Is there a way to animate this transition - it looks rather jarring.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem. I made a simple UIView category that fixes that.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface UIView (GCLibrary)

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat height;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat width;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat x;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat y;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "UIView+GCLibrary.h"


@implementation UIView (GCLibrary)

- (CGFloat) height {
    return self.frame.size.height;
}

- (CGFloat) width {
    return self.frame.size.width;
}

- (CGFloat) x {
    return self.frame.origin.x;
}

- (CGFloat) y {
    return self.frame.origin.y;
}

- (CGFloat) centerY {
    return self.center.y;
}

- (CGFloat) centerX {
    return self.center.x;
}

- (void) setHeight:(CGFloat) newHeight {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = newHeight;
    self.frame = frame;
}

- (void) setWidth:(CGFloat) newWidth {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.width = newWidth;
    self.frame = frame;
}

- (void) setX:(CGFloat) newX {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.x = newX;
    self.frame = frame;
}

- (void) setY:(CGFloat) newY {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y = newY;
    self.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

Comment: I ended up making the the exact same class methods but didn't think of appending it to the original UIView class! +1 for being practical and clever!

Comment: If you need something like this in `Swift` - feel free to use https://github.com/katleta3000/UIView-Frame

Answer (score 13):

UIView's also have a `center` property. If you just want to move the position rather than resize, you can just change that - eg:

`aView.center = CGPointMake(50, 200);`

Otherwise you would do it the way you posted.

Answer (score 7):

I found a similar approach (it uses a category as well) with gcamp's answer that helped me greatly [here](http://cocoaexposed.com/post/41413833163/positioning-uiview-with-ease). In your case is as simple as this:

```
aView.topLeft = CGPointMake(100, 200);
```

but if you want for example to centre horizontal and to the left with another view you can simply:

```
aView.topLeft = anotherView.middleLeft;
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution in the selected answer does not work in case of using Autolayout. If you are using Autolayout for views take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189362/animating-an-image-view-to-slide-upwards/14190042#14190042).

Answer (score 6):

`CGRectOffset` has since been replaced with the instance method `offsetBy`.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1454841-offsetby

For example, what used to be

```
aView.frame = CGRectOffset(aView.frame, 10, 10)
```

would now be

```
aView.frame = aView.frame.offsetBy(dx: CGFloat(10), dy: CGFloat(10))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
aView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, aView.frame.size.width, aView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: i think we were typing the same thing all at the same time.

Comment: I love the thrill of trying to have the best answer first.

Answer (score 2):

In my work we not use macros. So the solution provide by @TomSwift inspired to me. I see the implementation for CGRectMake and create the same CGRectSetPos but without macros.

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectSetPos(CGRect frame, CGFloat x, CGFloat y)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = frame.size.width; rect.size.height = frame.size.height;
  return rect;
}
```

To use I only put frame, X and Y

```
viewcontroller.view.frame = CGRectSetPos(viewcontroller.view.frame, 100, 100);
```

Work for me ^_^

Comment: I check the original implementation of CGRectMake and this is the way they (Apple) do it. So I follow them.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody needs light `Swift` extension to change `UIView` margins easily - you can use [this](https://github.com/katleta3000/UIView-Frame)

```
view.top = 16
view.right = self.width
view.bottom = self.height
self.height = view.bottom
```

Answer (score 2):

@TomSwift Swift 3 answer

```
aView.center = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150); // set center
```

Or

```
aView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: aView.frame.size.width, height: aView.frame.size.height ); // set new position exactly
```

Or

```
aView.frame = aView.frame.offsetBy(dx: CGFloat(10), dy: CGFloat(10)) // offset by an amount
```

Answer (score 1):

**swift**

```
view.frame = view.frame.offsetBy(dx: offsetX, dy: offsetY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 3 answer for anyone looking since Swift 3 does not accept "Make".

```
aView.center = CGPoint(x: 200, Y: 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(100,30);
[self setFrame:(CGRect){
      .origin = position,
      .size = self.frame.size
}];
```

This i save size parameters and change origin only.