# Programmatically added UITableView won't populate data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wish to create `UITableView` and a **custom** cell, and add them to my `UIViewController`.

If I layout `UITableView` from the storyboard onto my `UIViewController`,  *everything works fine with custom cell*.

But I realized that animation regarding its height is not very smooth - sometimes the table view disappears

So I decided to create/destroy a `UITableView` everytime I wish to do some animation, and add it as a subview to my `UIViewController`.

But the programmatically-added `UITableView` won't populate data.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var dataArr = [String]() // Holds data for UITableView
var tv: UITableView!     // Notice it's not @Outlet

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    dataArr = ["one", "two", "three"]


    // Create and add UITableView as drop down
    tv = UITableView()
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self

    createTableView()
}

func createTableView() {
    let w = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    tv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, w, 0)
    tv.rowHeight = 25.0

    // Register custom cell
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "searchCell", bundle: nil)
    tv.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "searchCell")

    self.view.addSubview(tv)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {
            self.tv.frame.size.height = 100
        }, completion: { (didFinish) in
            self.tv.reloadData()
        })
}

func destroyTableView() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations:
        {
            // Hide
            self.tv.frame.size.height = 0
        }, completion: { (didFinish) in
            self.tv.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}

// MARK: - UITableView
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: SearchCell = self.tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell") as! SearchCell
    cell.cellLabel.text = dataArr[indexPath.row]
    return cell;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line.

```
self.tv.frame.size.height = 100
```

Try setting the whole frame instead of just the height. Pretty sure a UIView's Frame's properties are read only.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537573/ios-frame-change-one-property-eg-width)

If that doesn't work. Maybe try implementing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```