# translate a UIImageView down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiviewanimation, cgrect

I am coding an iOS game and I am trying to move down an instance of a Tile (Tile being a subclass of UIImageView.)

Precisely, what I want is having my instance of Tile moving from point A(x,y) to point B(x,y+70) in 0.20s.

I already read that post, that describes a similar problem: [change position of the UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333361/change-position-of-the-uiimageview?rq=1)

I used the recommended code and adapted it to my case. So here is the code of the method I use:

```cs
- (void) moveTileDown {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.20
                          delay:1.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y + 70, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
}
```

But now, here is my problem. Instead of going from A(x,y) to B(x,y+70), when the method is called, my tile Jumps to C(x,y-70) and comes back to A in 0.20s.

In order to give more info, the moveTileDown method is called from a for loop that takes place in another controller

```
        for (int i=0; i <firstTileRow; i++){
            [[[_lines objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:firstTileColumn] moveTileDown];
            [[[_lines objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:secondTileColumn] moveTileDown];
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Replace this option `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` with `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn`.

Comment: @iphonic ok, updated :) (but that does not change the problem)

Comment: Now the question is when do you call the function `moveTileDown` ? can you update the full implementation?

Comment: @iphonic I added more details, and updated the description of my problem. Actualy, the tile does not come back from B to A, it jumps to C and comes back to A. The motion is the right one and in the right direction, but it does not start from the initial position of the tile.

Comment: Can you put `NSLog(@"Initial Frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));` at the first line of `moveTileDown ` function before the animation block and see the log..

Comment: @iphonic actually I found the pb. It's due to auto layout. I just unchecked "use auto layout" box on interface builder and I got the expected behaviour. I think I need to learn more about how auto layout works.