# Autolayout seems not working when changing view dimensions programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have custom subclass of a UITableViewCell with some constraints set.

Problem is when I try to change size of one view like this:

```
CGRect frm = CGRectMake(0, 0, someValue, 30);
cell.indentView.frame = frm;
```

other views, which depend on cell.indentView width, are not moving at all.

What can be the case?

This code will work:

```
// enumerate over all constraints
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in cell.indentView.constraints) {
    // find constraint on this view and with 'width' attribute
    if (constraint.firstItem == cell.indentView && constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeWidth)
    {
        // increase width of constraint
        constraint.constant = someValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: AutoLayout is so ugly, it made me cry. Happy Coding!

Comment: +1 to above autolayout haters. That's the worst of hell. You need to think a hundred times before using it in a project harder than trivial. I'd better add a few lines of code calculating frames on some screens.

Comment: @Rob And the worst part, it just feels like turning on itself even when you set the deployment target to >= iOS 5!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you cannot just change the frame of an object that has autolayout constraints (because constraints dictate the locations, not manually set `frame` properties ... the `frame` properties will be reset as constraints are reapplied). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189362/animating-an-image-view-to-slide-upwards/14190042#14190042) loosely related post in which it is demonstrated how to properly adjust a constraint to move a view. (In that case, we're animating, which is not the issue here, but it does demonstrate how how one adjusts a constraint to effect the movement of a `UIView`.)

In short, if you want to move a `UIView` within autolayout, you must not try to change the `frame`, but rather adjust the constraints themselves. This is simplified if you create `IBOutlet` references for the constraints themselves, at which point, you can adjust the `constant` of the `NSLayoutConstraint`.

---

**Update:**

Egor recommended enumerating the constraints and editing the one that matched the one in question. That works great, but personally, I prefer to have an `IBOutlet` for the specific constraint I want to edit rather than enumerating them and hunting the one in question. If you had an `IBOutlet` called `indentViewWidthConstraint` for the width `NSLayoutConstraint` of the `indentView`, you could then simply:

```
self.indentViewWidthConstraint.constant = newIndentConstantValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to tell the framework to update e.g. by calling `setNeedsLayout`, `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` or `layoutIfNeeded`.
See the documentation for [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816) for the proper usage.

Comment: This wasn't enough for me - had to change the constraint as per the question and the other answer.