# Core Animation and UIImageView returning to starting position

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIImageView that I'm moving across the screen based on a user swiping.  I accomplish this using Core Animation:

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

 movingView.frame = theRect;

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

It always starts out fine, but partway through going from its original location to the "theRect" location, it stops and the UIImageView jumps back to its starting point.  It's never at the same point.  Sometimes gets almost all the way through before jumping back, sometimes only barely moving then jumping back.  No other code is running after this.  I've tried changing the duration and it doesn't seem to matter.

If I add in:

```
 [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(completeAnimation:finished:context:)];
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
```

Then it actually delays until the Duration is complete and runs the selector, even if the image itself stops and returns to its starting point almost immediately.

Hopefully someone can give me some hints at what might be going on here.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in the code you posted.  The animation getting triggered twice is my best guess based on the symptoms.  Can NSLog(@"hello") just before the commit?  You should see only one "hello".

Comment: It does only get triggered once.  However, I figured out the issue here.  When I unchecked the "Use Autolayout" for the storyboard, it works as it should.  While it is checked, it does not.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something here, if this is a bug, or there's a way programatically to not let this happen.  If anyone knows, I would love to hear how to keep Autolayout on and do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using autolayout, you can animate the changing of the constraint, not animating the change of the frame (because when constraints are reapplied, the original location will be restored). See [Animating an image view to slide upwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189362/animating-an-image-view-to-slide-upwards/14190042#14190042) for an example.

Comment: I'm sure there's good reasons for Autolayout and it's new to the system, but every time I turn around there's reasons to uncheck Autolayout.  It seems overly complex and the previous way to manage views seems simpler and more straightforward.  Is there a good tutorial somewhere that explains why Autolayout is a good thing (if it even is)?  But thanks for the example.  It helps.

Comment: @MichaelReiland I must have missed your comment here: I'd suggest the WWDC 2012 videos including an [introduction](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202), the [autolayout by example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=232) video, and [Mastering Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228) video.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for! everything was working fine on my iphone version of the app but I could not figure out why my uiimageview kept returning to its starting location everytime I had a popup or other actions happened on the ipad version. I Turned off autolayout and everything started working correctly.