# NSTimer blocks other animations

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nstimer

## Description

I have a `NSTimer` that updates an `UILabel` every second. I have another `UIImageView` that slides in the screen when a `UIButton` is pressed.

## Issue

The problem is that when the `NSTimer` updates the `UILabel`, the animation of the `UImageView` stops from completing.

## Question

Please can you tell me how can i update the timer without messing with the other animations?

Comment: Show us some code. You're probably doing too much on the main thread

Comment: @Stavash He probably just has autolayout turned on.

Comment: Sounds like a very good bet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common symptom of having [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html) turned on but are probably trying to slide it across the screen by adjusting the `frame` or `center`. Auto layout is a iOS 6+ feature that controls the location and size of various `UIView` elements. Unfortunately, when you have auto layout on, every time you change a label's value, it will reapply the constraints that dictate where the label should be positioned, defeating your attempts to animate it.

Two solutions:

1. Turn off auto layout by opening up your storyboard or NIB, click on the first "document inspector" tab on the rightmost panel, and then uncheck "Use Autolayout".

   [image: show autolayout]
2. If you want to use autolayout, animate the moving of the control by changing constraints rather than changing `frame` or `center`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190042/1271826) for an example of how you can create an `IBOutlet` for a constraint and then change that constraint programmatically in an `animateWithDuration` block.

#### References:

- [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1)
- [Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)
- [Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228)
- [Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=232)

Comment: Rob, thank you for your detailed answer. I will check both solutions and let you know.

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Both solutions are working, but i want to target iOS 5, so i will use the second one.

Thanks again :).