# Changing UILabel text messes up animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uianimation

My app has to do a calculation and animation based on a choice the user makes and I need to update a `UILabel` before it is used in the animation, the problem is whenever I set the `UILabel` text it messes up the animation and I have no idea why. I have tried [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; before the changing the `UILabel` text and still no good. I even tried programmatically calling an `IBAction` and changing `UILabel` text from that block and it still messes up the animation. Nothing seems to work and it is definitely about timing as changing the `UILabel` text in viewDidLoad does work fine. I also checked if it is a Storyboard problem by changing another `UILabel`'s text before the animation and the same problem occurs. If it helps at all here is the animation code:

```
    -(IBAction) swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
multiply.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
subtract.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
add.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
divide.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
signcircle.frame = CGRectMake(145.0f, 70.0f, signcircle.frame.size.width,signcircle.frame.size.height);
sign.frame = CGRectMake(152.0f, 68.0f, sign.frame.size.width,sign.frame.size.height);
type=@"multiply"; 
if(fivebutton.highlighted){
    circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
    multiply.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.35f, 1.35f);
    multiply.frame = CGRectMake(120.0f, 248.0f, multiply.frame.size.width, multiply.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25f animations:^{
        add.frame = CGRectMake(130.0f, 202.0f, add.frame.size.width, add.frame.size.height);
        add.alpha=1.0;
        subtract.frame = CGRectMake(82.0f, 255.0f, subtract.frame.size.width, subtract.frame.size.height);
        subtract.alpha=1.0;
        divide.frame = CGRectMake(178.0f, 255.0f, divide.frame.size.width, divide.frame.size.height);
        divide.alpha=1.0;
        multiply.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        multiply.frame = CGRectMake(130.0f, 305.0f, multiply.frame.size.width, divide.frame.size.height);
        multiply.alpha=1.0;
        circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        circle.alpha=1.0;
    UIImage *downimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"multiplydown.png"];
    [multiply setImage:downimage];
    onebutton.alpha=0.1;
    one.alpha=0.1;
    twobutton.alpha=0.1;
    two.alpha=0.1;
    threebutton.alpha=0.1;
    three.alpha=0.1;
    fourbutton.alpha=0.1;
    four.alpha=0.1;
    sixbutton.alpha=0.1;
    six.alpha=0.1;
    fivebutton.alpha=0.0;
    sevenbutton.alpha=0.1;
    seven.alpha=0.1;
    eightbutton.alpha=0.1;
    eight.alpha=0.1;
    ninebutton.alpha=0.1;
    nine.alpha=0.1;
    zerobutton.alpha=0.1;
    zero.alpha=0.1;
    decimalbutton.alpha=0.1;
    decimal.alpha=0.1;
    equalsbutton.alpha=0.1;
    equals.alpha=0.1;
    }];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

In this case the `UILabel` text change causes "add","subtract","divide" and "multiply" (`UIImageView`'s) to merge together instead of spreading as the animation is supposed to.

```
    -(void) fiveTapEnded{
var2.hidden=NO;
if ([type isEqual:@"add"]) {
    NSLog(@"Is add");
}
if ([type isEqual:@"subtract"]) {
    NSLog(@"Is subtract");
}
if ([type isEqual:@"multiply"]) {
    var1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    var1.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 70.0f, var1.frame.size.width,var1.frame.size.height);
    var2.frame = CGRectMake(145.0f, 70.0f, var2.frame.size.width,var2.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25f animations:^{
        add.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
        add.alpha=0.0;
        multiply.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
        multiply.alpha=0.0;
        divide.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
        divide.alpha=0.0;
        circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
        circle.alpha=0.0;
        subtract.alpha=0.0;
        var1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, var1.frame.size.width,var1.frame.size.height);
        var2.frame = CGRectMake(185.0f, 20.0f, var2.frame.size.width,var2.frame.size.height);
        signcircle.frame = CGRectMake(145.0f, 30.0f, signcircle.frame.size.width,signcircle.frame.size.height);
        sign.frame = CGRectMake(152.0f, 26.5f, sign.frame.size.width,sign.frame.size.height);
        result.frame = CGRectMake(8.0f, 100.0f, result.frame.size.width,result.frame.size.height);
        signcircle.alpha=1.0;
        sign.alpha=1.0;
        var2.alpha=1.0;
        result.alpha=1.0;
        one.alpha=1.0;
        onebutton.alpha=1.0;
        twobutton.alpha=1.0;
        two.alpha=1.0;
        three.alpha=1.0;
        threebutton.alpha=1.0;
        fourbutton.alpha=1.0;
        four.alpha=1.0;
        sixbutton.alpha=1.0;
        six.alpha=1.0;
        five.alpha=1.0;
            fivebutton.alpha=1.0;;
        sevenbutton.alpha=1.0;
        seven.alpha=1.0;
        eightbutton.alpha=1.0;
        eight.alpha=1.0;
        ninebutton.alpha=1.0;
        nine.alpha=1.0;
        zerobutton.alpha=1.0;
        zero.alpha=1.0;
        decimalbutton.alpha=1.0;
        decimal.alpha=1.0;
        equalsbutton.alpha=1.0;
        equals.alpha=1.0;
        }];
    [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [self functionToBeCalled:self];
}
if ([type isEqual:@"divide"]) {
    NSLog(@"Is divide");
}
}
```

In this case it causes "var1" and "var2" (`UILabel`'s) to not move upwards.

I understand its confusing, I've been searching everywhere and can't find a similar problem so this was kind of my last resort, if anyone has any solution or tips that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, by "messes up animation", you mean that it's going back to its starting location, then you probably have autolayout on. The autolayout constraints are automatically reapplied when you change the `UILabel`, and thus any animations that entail the changing of the frame will be thwarted. Bottom line, when using autolayout with constraints that dictate the layout, you should not be changing `frame` or `center` values manually.

That obviously leaves two possible remedies:

1. Simplest, you could turn off auto layout. Then the setting of the label won't be triggering any constraints to be applied. See [NSTimer blocks other animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376074/nstimer-blocks-other-animations/16376214#16376214) for very similar issue.
2. If you want to keep auto layout turned on, then you shouldn't be animating by changing the `frame` (or `center`) properties of controls, but rather you should create `IBOutlet` references for the appropriate constraints, and then animate them by changing the `constant` property. See [Animating an image view to slide upwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189362/animating-an-image-view-to-slide-upwards/14190042#14190042)