# Animation not Shown When Calling it First Time

Tags: iphone, ios, uianimation

I have one simple animation:

```
- (void)showMenu
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(296, -150, 432, 356);

    [self.buttonMenu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_arrow_up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.scrollView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

When I call this animation the first time, just the image of my button changes, 
the position of my scrollview does not change.

Everything works correctly, after I called my `showMenu` method twice.

- I call `showMenu`. the image of the button changes. position of `scrollview` not
- I call another method to reset everything. image of button changes. position of `scrollview` not
- I call `showMenu`. the image of the button changes. position of `scrollview` changes
- from now on it works every time I call `showmenu`

the second method is `closeMenu`:

```
- (void)closeMenu
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(296, -317, 432, 356);

    [self.buttonMenu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_arrow_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

So why does it work just when I click it twice?

Comment: Yes auto layout is turned on

Comment: but why is it working after the second use? without problems and complaining even if i reload the ui?

Comment: I would recommend just not using autolayout.  It ends up being much more of a pain than it is worth

Comment: Disabeling autolayout solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when i perform a `UIAnimation` and simultaneously adding a `UITableView` programmatically. The frame of `UIView` changes but it will not update in display.

To solve this problem call your method using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a delay of 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have autolayout turned on, you may want to wary about changing the `frame` of a view. Unfortunately, when the constraints are reapplied (which triggered by a myriad of seemingly innocuous actions, such as setting a text label, etc.), your manually set `frame` will be replaced with values governed by the constraints.

You're probably not seeing this problem manifest itself the second time time you call this routine because you're probably not doing anything immediately thereafter that causes constraints to be reapplied. Even with autolayout on, you can sometime change a `frame` manually, and it will work, but as soon as constraints are reapplied, the `frame` may get reset.

There are two solutions:

1. If using auto layout, you can animate the changing of constraint constants. See the latter part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190042/1271826) for an example of how to create an `IBOutlet` for constraint and then changing the `constant` property within an animation block.
2. You can also simply disable autolayout.