# UIView is not aminating for the first time

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation

I am trying to animate a UIView on button click.
It does appear on first click but only after that.

```
@IBAction func viewDetails(sender: AnyObject) {

     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5 as NSTimeInterval, animations: {
                   println(self.viewDetailsView.center.x)
                    println(self.viewDetailsView.hidden)
                    self.viewDetailsView.hidden = false
                    self.viewDetailsView.center = CGPointMake(self.viewDetailsView.center.x - 4000, self.viewDetailsView.center.y)
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: {
                        finished in
                        self.detailsVisible = true
                }) }
```

Comment: you mean to say it work when second time clicking..?

Comment: Yes, after first click it works every time.

Comment: A little more context would be good. Where are you calling this from?

Comment: I am calling this in an IBAction of  a uiButton.

Comment: I found the solution. If you are using auto layout constraints, then you should update the constraints to create animations.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301743/animation-not-shown-when-calling-it-first-time

Answer (score 1):

Trying this:

```
@IBAction func viewDetails(sender: AnyObject) {

    println(self.viewDetailsView.center.x)
    println(self.viewDetailsView.hidden)
    self.viewDetailsView.hidden = false
    self.viewDetailsView.center = CGPointMake(self.viewDetailsView.center.x - 4000, self.viewDetailsView.center.y)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5 as NSTimeInterval, animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { finished in
        self.detailsVisible = true
    }) 
}
```