# UIPickerView position change with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uipickerview

I came across this problem, and I'm not sure how to solve.
I want to animate the position of my pickerView but it wont change it's position as long as i am using autolayout and I can't take autolayout off

Any advice?
Thanks

**EDIT1**

This is what i have, the picker is behind the fray view.

[image]

This is what i want to accomplish.
1)move the picker to the upper limit of the blue button
2)move the grey view to the upper limit of the picker view

[image]

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or adding Auto Layout constraints programmatically?

Comment: Not sure, where you're making a mistake. A screenshot in your question would be very helpful for others to understand the problem.

Comment: Have you tried just setting a new frame on code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of research and reading.
The answer to my problem was solved by working with the constraints constant of my UI

If you want you can read it in this well explained post

[Autolayout constraints modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189362/animating-an-image-view-to-slide-upwards/14190042#14190042)