# UIImageView only set size or origin

Tags: xcode, uiimageview

Is there a way to only set the size/origin and not the other for a UIImageView? Right now I have to make the CGRect's first two or last two arguments the same as it was before.

Comment: this thread should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161096/simple-way-to-change-the-position-of-uiview

Comment: Oh... Thank you very much! I thought I had searched enough, but evidently I didn't.